# Different fixed effects in a LMM using lme4 package in R

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have fitted a LMM in R using the lme4 package in R of the following form:

```
lmer(y ~ (1|time)+(1|subject)+group)
```

Where *y* is my response variable, *time* indicates the measurement time point and *subject* the individual, from which the data was taken. *group* is my fixed factor with two levels, lets call them "A" and "B". The fixed effects results for this are:

A/Intercept: "44.4"
B: "38.1"

I used another dataset with two different groups "B" and "C", where "B" is the exact (!) same group as in the first trial. I fitted the same LMM on the new data

```
lmer(y ~ (1|time)+(1|subject)+group)
```

where, as already mentioned, *group* "B" is the exact same *group* with the exact same data as before. The fixed effects estimates in this case are:

"B"/Intercept: "38.15"
"C": "38.24"

As one can see, the fixed effects estimates for "B" are not the same in both cases. I know that LMMs usually estimate their fixed effects through shrinkage towards the mean (and as far as I understand, this means that the whole dataset is considered while estimating the effects, so especially smaller sample sizes benefit from the information of the whole dataset), so I didn't expect the results to be exactly the same for both datasets, even if a subset of the data stays the same. But what made me insecure is that I tried a lot of other response variables *y_1, y_2, y_3,* ... in the same setting (with the two different datasets but the same group "B") and they result in the exact same estimates. So the difference is only given for response variable *y*. I would like to ask: Is it normal, that fixed effetcs estimates differ in my case?

Thank you! :)

---

Thank you very much for your response! :)

*"... you probably meant 'random effects'. No shrinkage is applied to the fixed effects."*

This was exactly my problem, as I assumed that fixed effects are estimated as a mean of the respective group, while random effects are estimated via shrinkage. However, my logic told me that the group mean for group B should not change if I do not change this group data in both models. Therefore, I thought that shrinkage would also affect the fixed effects, which is why I assumed a change in the estimation of the fixed effects. And just to underline it once again: The data for group B is the same not only for the group factor but also for time and subject - but I think you have already taken that into account in your answer.

*"Remember that via the intercept for B you are estimating the expected outcome when group is set to level B, conditional on time and subject. By replacing group A with C, you are changing some of the data for two out of these three variables."*

Many, many thanks for this statement, that seems very comprehensible to me and removes the uncertainty I described.

*"Did you check how large the difference actually is when you print the same number of digits in both cases?"*

I don't think it has anything to do with the optimisation, in the meantime I have tried out the models on other response variables and the difference is sometimes also larger natural numbers. It is probably more due to how much the random effects data varies.

*"To see in more detail why this is happening, you would need to post a reproducible data example, I suppose."*

I would like to do that, how can I share data sets? Sorry, I am quite inexperienced in such forums.

*"By the way, from a modelling point of view, it is beneficial to not split the analysis into multiple pairwise comparisons, but instead to include the full data set with all groups in one model - but you are probably aware of that."*

Thank you for the advice, I am aware of that. The study is explorative and makes a pairwise comparison for all groups and also a model that compares all groups at the same time.

Thanks again for taking the time to reply! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: You could just add a block with a coulple of rows of your dataset, for example. It seems to me there is no benefit for doing the pairwise comparisons (from what I get abour your data and problem). You can get inference for all pairwise comparisons from the full model, while getting better estimates for the random effects, bc they can draw on more data

Comment: Thank you for your reply! A full model with all three groups was also fitted. The aim of the pairwise comparison is not producing final results but exploring the data from a different perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here ...

> usually estimate their fixed effects through shrinkage towards the mean

... you probably meant 'random effects'. No shrinkage is applied to the fixed effects.

Did you check how large the difference actually is when you print the same number of digits in both cases? Is it in a range which could be explained by numerical instabilities in the optimization algorithm?

In any case, there is no reason to assume that the estimates must be identical. That's because, in your model, you are estimating the **joint** distribution of all parameters, and you have more parameters than just the fixed *group* intercepts. So even if the data for B are the same in both models (and therefore also is the raw sample mean in group B, for example), you are still changing the data which goes into the estimation of the *time* and *subject* effects. This can affect all other parameters as well.

Remember that via the intercept for B you are estimating the expected outcome when *group* is set to level B, conditional on *time* and *subject*. By replacing group A with C, you are changing some of the data for two out of these three variables.

To see in more detail why this is happening, you would need to post a reproducible data example, I suppose.

By the way, from a modelling point of view, it is beneficial to not split the analysis into multiple pairwise comparisons, but instead to include the full data set with all groups in one model - but you are probably aware of that.